# NullPointerException:Attempt toget length of null array

Tags: java, android

i need to create playlist from sdcard when i run my application it generate null pointer exception attempt get length of null array.  because it could not read file from sdcard. But i have song files in emulator sdcard folder.Here is the code i have tried but it not work please help me to fix the problem.

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
     public boolean accept(File dir,String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3")); 
      }
}
public class Audio extends ListActivity{
private MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
private final String SD_PATH=new String("/sdcard/");
private List<String> songs=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio);
    updatePlaylist();
    Button stpbtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.stpbtn);

    stpbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
private void updatePlaylist()
{
    try
    {
         File home = new File (SD_PATH);
        if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0)
        {
            for(File file:home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()))
            {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Audio.this,R.layout.song_item,songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

here is my audio.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="401dp" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stpbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stpbtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is song_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: any exception trace? Which line?

Comment: it show in the line number 45. where if statement try to compare with array length.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDoc for File.listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FileFilter-):

> The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So you need to check this explicitly.

```
File home = new File (SD_PATH);
File[] listOfFiles = home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
if(listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

And/Or work in a check that the file is in fact a directory:

```
 File home = new File (SD_PATH);
 if(!home.isDirectory()) {
     // Error case, handle it.
 }
```